# I've linked an Awesome Fonts logo to another website in HTML but it wants to look in my website directory and not link directly to the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So at the bottom of my website I have a social media section that links to each of my social media accounts. I have gotten three of them to work using the Awesome Fonts CDN. But my fourth one refuses to cooperate and I don't know why.

```
<a href="https://github.com/Myprofile"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
```

This bit of HTML will link the github icon to my github account perfectly fine. But when I want the linked in logo to work using the following code-

```
<a href="www.linkedin.com/in/MyProfile"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
```

I get

```
Not Found

The requested URL /â€œINSETURLHEREâ€ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to...
```

Oddly enough when I mouse over the logo (which does show up) it tells me it is trying to direct me to www.mywebsite.com/www.linkedin.com/mypage

Why would the last link using the exact same syntax want to search my website for that page, when the other links work just fine? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you really have fancy quotes?

Comment: missing `http://`?

Comment: Wow didn't even see that, I'm not sure where those came from but it might be because I copy and pasted the link not sure. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No its not http, I have attempted putting the github link in the same space as the linkedin one including the https and it still gives me the same error but with github instead.

Comment: Try an agnostic scheme: `//www.linkedin... `

Comment: Note that you [**must** include the protocol to have _predictable_ link behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4.1). Links are resolved by using the Base (which is often `[your domain]/` by default) and then following [RFC1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt). Simply writing `"www.xxxxx.com"` will (rightfully) result in `[yourdomain]/www.xxxxx.com` due to this resolution process. Links without a protocol (or some disambiguating marks, like `//`) will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @SamMullinix Have you also changed the fancy quotes in your HTML file? I believe `â€œ` represents mis-encoded opening curly quotes (and `â€` closing ones). It's seeing the curly quotes as part of the URL. (You should _also_ add `http(s)://` before the URL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `link` tag's `href` attribute needs to be prefixed by `//` or `http://` in order to tell a browser to look outside of your domain.

The primary issue was that the `href` was using  "smart" quotes instead of standard quotes.

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/8tg1TfP.png) This is what I get when I do that. I have tried putting http in front of it and it doesn't seem to care. I'm beginning to think it could be the linked in logo that is broken somehow. I had to do an FA update and had to delete and redownload the directory because I was running on an older version that didn't have it. That's the only diagnosis I have at the moment.

Comment: @SamMullinix the "smart" quotes are hard-coded into your application. Replace the quotes around the href with `Shift` + `"`

Comment: @rockrest is correct, in your code editor you are using "smart" quotes (the kind that change direction depending on what side they are on) and that is why it is showing â€œ on the 404 page.

Comment: edited to so the actual solution is easier to find. all credit for this goes to @rockerest

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide "https://" or "http://" as a prefix